# How to avoid Google App Invites showing a Snackbar?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

Is there a way to avoid Google App Invites showing a Snackbar when invitation is sent? Or can I change the position where it's showing?

Comment: In the [google-services](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services) demo implementation, you can just disable it by not explicitly call `showMessage()` which has snackbar viewgroup invocation.

Comment: In the google-services demo there is no call to showMessage() when invitations are sent: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/appinvites/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/appinvite/MainActivity.java

Comment: See [carefully](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/appinvites/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/appinvite/MainActivity.java#L155) :)

Comment: I see that a SnackBar is shown in `showMessage()` method. So the SnackBar is shown when such method is called. As you can see, such method is only called when there is a failure sending invitations. When invitations are sent, there is no call to such method: [see](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/appinvites/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/appinvite/MainActivity.java#L138)

Comment: Heh, you are right. I can't find such implementation in the library itself. Please update here if you find any. Maybe it's still in beta it doesn't have the ability to customize it, I dunno.

Comment: Nop. I'm still waiting for a fix